# CheckBox Document Properties on SharePoint 2010 Document Libary

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, word

I created a document library and add columns to this library. Text, DateTime and Choice fields can be used on Word document as document properties. But I can't use CheckBox type column on document properties. Is there a way to use check box?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I just added checkboxes from developer tab.